# How to run testng from both command line and eclipse

Tags: maven, testng, pom.xml

By using below code i can able to run from Command line. Here i am passing browser variable from command line:
`mvn test -DsuiteXmlFile=testng.xml -Dbrowsers=chrome`

```
<systemPropertyVariables>
    <environment>${browsers}</environment>
</systemPropertyVariables>
```

But the same way i tried to run from eclipse testng.xml file. I couldn't able to run. I am getting below error

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: .\data\null.xlsx (The system cannot find the file specified) at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source) at java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source) at utils.DataInputProvider.getAllSheetData(DataInputProvider.java:17) at wrappers.LoopCommerce.getData(project.java:48) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85) at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:136) at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:441) at org.testng.internal.Invoker.handleParameters(Invoker.java:1300) at org.testng.internal.Invoker.createParameters(Invoker.java:1015) at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1104) at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125) at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108) at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:771) at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:621) at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:357) at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:352) at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:310) at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:259) at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52) at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86) at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1199) at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1124) at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1032) at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132) at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230) at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)
```

Pom.xml:

```
   <build>
  <!-- To define the plugin version in your parent POM -->
  <pluginManagement>
   <plugins>
   <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.21.0</version>
     <configuration>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <environment>${browsers}</environment>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
      <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>src/main/resources/${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>
      </suiteXmlFiles>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
 </plugins>
```

Class file:

```
@BeforeClass
@Parameters({"environment", "saksurl"})
public void setData(String environment, String saksurl) {
    browserName = environment;
    url = saksurl;
    dataSheetName="TC001";
}
```

Comment: please share the code where you read the systemPropertyVariables and also the complete code in the pom.xml pertaining to mvn surefire plugin

Comment: @Sighil i added pom.xml code and class file code